# How to parse the output of vars() neatly?

Tags: python, object, io, ipython

Is there a way in which to see the attributes of a Python object via `vars`, but with the output formatting being clean, and it not showing all the values of each attribute? (For example, a large array taking up all the screen). I basically just want a nice clean list of its attributes.

Comment: Have you tried the standard `pprint`?

Comment: The display of the ipthon `%whos` would be nice, but I don't see a way of invoking that on a dictionary like `vars()`.

Comment: @hpaulj The ipython %whos? ...

Comment: `%whos` gives a nice compact view of most of the variables in the current interactive session.  It's an expanded version of `%who`.  `%` is the prefix for `ipython` `magic` commands, and depending on the configuration might be optional.

Comment: @hpaulj I think I would contend myself with just a "pretty" list of all the dictionary keys at this point. Ideally I WOULD like a pretty list of keys and their corresponding values, but I don't know how that would work when some of the values are large arrays/matricies that just end up monopolizing the real-estate on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of the keys of the object's `vars`, that'd be

```
list(vars(whatever))
```

or you could go through the keys and print them on their own lines:

```
for attr in vars(whatever):
    print(attr)
```

or you could pretty-print the dict with [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) (though it might not be any prettier than IPython's default pretty-printing):

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(vars(whatever))
```

or you could just code up whatever you think would be a readable way to view the information `vars` gives you. You're always free to write your own code.

There's also `dir(whatever)`, which aims to provide a list of the object's attributes useful for interactive inspection. `dir(whatever)` will usually be different from `list(vars(whatever))`; for example, it'll include methods.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a list of the attribute names, the `vars` `keys`? Or the full dictionary, `keys` and `values`? Depending on the object class `vars` could be empty, just a few scalars and strings, or a large and complex set of lists, arrays, etc. Without a general purpose 'pretty-printer' you can not generate a clear display for all classes. It's the purpose of the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods to produce a useful display of the objects attributes.

In my current `ipython` session

The variables are:

```
In [97]: who
M    argparse    arr     b   choices     forbool     np  nr  parser  
product  sparse  sys
```

One is user defined function with an empty vars

```
In [99]: forbool
Out[99]: <function __main__.forbool>

In [100]: vars(forbool)
Out[100]: {}
```

One is sparse matrix, with a modest number of attributes.  This example has only 5 nonzero values, so the arrays are quite small.  Yes, numpy arrays can be very large.  Their display is controlled by `numpy` code.

```
In [101]: M
Out[101]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5 stored elements in LInked List format>

In [102]: vars(M)
Out[102]: 
{'_shape': (5, 5),
 'data': array([[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]], dtype=object),
 'dtype': dtype('float64'),
 'maxprint': 50,
 'rows': array([[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]], dtype=object)}
```

`argparse` is an imported module, with many vars.  One, the `doc` takes up nearly a page.

```
In [103]: len(vars(argparse))
Out[103]: 52
```

`arr` is an array, and doesn't have a `__dict__`, and `vars(arr)` gives an error.

This is the `whos` display for this display.  arrays are displayed in a condensed form that is unique to `ipython`.

```
In [108]: %whos
Variable   Type              Data/Info
--------------------------------------
M          lil_matrix          (0, 0)   1.0\n  (1, 1)   1.<...> (3, 3)  1.0\n  (4, 4)   1.0
argparse   module            <module 'argparse' from '<...>b/python3.5/argparse.py'>
arr        ndarray           10x3: 30 elems, type `int32`, 120 bytes
b          ndarray           4x2: 8 elems, type `int32`, 32 bytes
choices    list              n=16
forbool    function          <function forbool at 0xb52950bc>
np         module            <module 'numpy' from '/us<...>kages/numpy/__init__.py'>
nr         int               3
parser     ArgumentParser    ArgumentParser(prog='ipyt<...>r='error', add_help=True)
product    type              <class 'itertools.product'>
sparse     module            <module 'scipy.sparse' fr<...>cipy/sparse/__init__.py'>
sys        module            <module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

You could write a pretty printer.  Here's a start:

```
def pprt(var):
    for k,v in vars(var).items():
        if isinstance(v, np.ndarray):
            astr = 'array {},{}'.format(v.dtype, v.shape)
        if isinstance(v, (list, tuple, dict)):
            if len(v)>10:
                astr = 'big '+type(v)
            else:
                astr = str(v)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            astr = v[:20]
        else:
            astr = str(v)
        print(k,':',astr)
```

For the sparse matrix

```
In [123]: pprt(M)
_shape : (5, 5)
dtype : float64
rows : [[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]]
data : [[1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
maxprint : 50
```

But for `argparse` `parser` object, it is clearly inadequate:

```
In [124]: pprt(parser)
conflict_handler : error
usage : None
prefix_chars : -
_action_groups : [<argparse._ArgumentGroup object at 0xb0c802ac>, <argparse._ArgumentGroup object at 0xb0c99ccc>]
_mutually_exclusive_groups : []
allow_abbrev : True
_optionals : <argparse._ArgumentGroup object at 0xb0c99ccc>
prog : ipython3
description : None
_actions : [_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None), _StoreAction(option_strings=['--k'], dest='k', nargs=None, const=None, default=100, type=<class 'int'>, choices=None, help='numbers, %(default)s', metavar=None)]
....
```

The object has many attributes; some have long class names.  Some are dictionaries with a few keys, but long values.  I'd have to do some sort of recursion to compress those.  So it's possible to write a compact displayer, but it will be a lot of work.